# JSON mime type on IIS Express with a POST request

Tags: javascript, json, extjs, iis-express

I am using Visual Studio 2013 with **IIS Express**.

My html page has a JavaScript (EXTJS) which is calling a **file.json** on **HTTP POST method**.
and I get "**HTTP Error 405.0 - Method Not Allowed**"

I tried adding below stuff in web.config

```
<system.webServer>
    <staticContent>
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".json" mimeType="application/json" />
    </staticContent>
  </system.webServer>
```

Ran below command on command prompt

```
appcmd set config /section:staticContent /+[fileExtension='JSON',mimeType='application/x-javascript']
```

Nothing helps.
I am able to access the .json file with GET request, like `http://localhost/file.json`, but not with POST request.

Here is my ExtJS code calling that JSON file

```
Ext.onReady(function () {
    var tree = new Ext.tree.TreePanel({
        renderTo: 'tree-div',
        title: 'My Task List',
        height: 300,
        width: 400,
        useArrows: true,
        autoScroll: true,
        animate: true,
        enableDD: true,
        containerScroll: true,
        rootVisible: false,
        frame: true,
        root: {
            nodeType: 'async'
        },
      dataUrl: 'file.json'
    });

    tree.getRootNode().expand(true);
});
```

file.json has below structured JSON

```
[{
    text: 'To Do', 
    cls: 'folder',
    children: [{
        text: 'Go jogging',
        leaf: true,
        checked: false
    },{
        text: 'Take a nap',
        leaf: true,
        checked: false
    },{
        text: 'Climb Everest',
        leaf: true,
        checked: false
    }]
},.....
```

Comment: What is the point of posting to a static file?

Comment: its actually not posting, its getting data from that file. but the ajax call is going a POST

Comment: So the TreePanel is making a POST request when trying to read the nodes from file.json? Also your code has `check-nodes.json` not `file.json`.

Comment: You are right "TreePanel is making a POST request".I missed changing the file name in code. But it is same file name on both places. I will edit the question to avoid this confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the `requestMethod` in the TreePanel configuration to be `GET` to force it to make GET requests instead of POST.

```
var tree = new Ext.tree.TreePanel({
    ...
    requestMethod: 'GET',
    ...
});
```

Comment: That worked. But how can I make the POST work as well? will that be needed in any case?

Comment: In my opinion, unless the user is creating nodes(i.e. the state of the application changes) it should be a GET. You would have to change the request to a script to be able to do POST requests also if you want the nodes to change dynamically.